# Multiple instances of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I install Multiple instances of SQl Server Express Edition (2005) on same DB server, will there be any licensing issue? DB is used by web sites.

Since SQL Server Express Edition is free, but I don't know if there is any limitation in describing the word "FREE"

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can I install multiple named instances without any licensing issue?

Answer (score 0):

No, there shouldn't be a problem. You still have the limits in place though.

Just be sure to set them up to run on different ports.